# Matlab nonlinear dynamic with equilibrium point.

Tags: matlab

I have this problem to solve:

Consider a system with the dynamics given by

```
xdot=x^3-7x^2+7x+15
```

where x is the position and `xdot` the velocity.

How can I Generate MATLAB code to plot a flow diagram `xdot` vs. `x` for this system and determine the three equilibrium points. My solution should be a vector named "`eq_points`" where `x=eq_points`(i) is an equilibrium point.

```
x=?
xdot=?
eq_points=?
```

I have try this :

```
xdot=@(x)(x^3-7*x^2+7*x+15)
```

and then

```
fplot(xdot,[-1000 1000])
```

I see the plot but how can I answer these three questions :

```
x=?
xdot=?
eq_points=?
```

Please I am novice in Matlab any help will be great.

Comment: The purpose is to find equilibrium points

Answer (score 1):

That is a simple Polynomial. Equilibrium points are in this case the roots of the polynomial. The polynomial representation in Matlab is done by creating a vector of the coefficients.

```
% xdot=x^3-7*x^2+7*x+15;
p = [1, -7, 7, 15]; % polynomial representation in Matlab

x = [-2:0.1:6]; % good xrange for visualization
figure
plot(x, polyval(p, x)) % evaluate polynomial p at x and plot
r = roots(p); % roots of polynomial (5, 3 and -1)

hold on;
plot(r, polyval(p, r), 'ro') % polyval(p, r) should be very close to [0, 0, 0]
```

The result looks like this:[image]

Edit: Alternative

You can also use your anonymous function to find *one* root at a time by `fzero(xdot, x0)` where `x0` is the starting point to iterate from. Depending on the starting point, you find different roots. As examples

```
xdot=@(x)(x^3-7*x^2+7*x+15);

fzero(xdot, 0)

ans =

    -1

fzero(xdot, 2)

ans =

     3

fzero(xdot, 10)

ans =

    5.0000
```